# Is it possible to have a empty numpy array with the shape of (n,m,3) where m can be a different number depend of n?

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to have a empty numpy array with the shape of (n,m,3) where m can be a different number depending n[i] ?

I have tried everything

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `empty`?  `[]` is an empty list.  `np.ones([0,2,3])` might be described as 'empty' because it does not contain an elements.  An array cannot have varying sizes on any dimension; that is, it can't be "ragged"

Comment: numpy doesn't record a different size per row. Once you've defined `m`, it has to be valid for each nth row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. When you instantiate the array, you must pick a fixed number for each dimension of the shape.

In geometrical terms, the shape of a 3-dimensional NumPy array must form a rectangular cuboid. It cannot be ragged. This is by design, as it allows for efficient computations. Also, many operations would be harder to define and less intuitive for irregularly shaped arrays.

What you can do, of course, is to pick `m` as the maximum of all the values you need and just not use some of the resulting cells.